# Is it possible to combine those two regex or improve my code?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know if there is a way to combine those two regex below OR a way to combine my two tasks in another way.

```
1) /(<\/[a-z]>|<[a-z]*>)/g
2) /\s{2,}/g
```

Specifically, they are used to replace this:

```
This is <b>a test</b> and this <i> is also a test</i>
```

Into this:

```
This is <b> a test </b> and this <i> is also a test </i>
```

The first regex is used to add a space before and after every opening and closing tags and the second regex, is used to match every occurence of two or more space characters to be removed.

Here is the code

```
var inputString = 'This is <b>a test</b> and this <i> is also a test</i>',
    spacedTags = inputString.replace(/(<\/[a-z]>|<[a-z]*>)/g, ' $1 '),
    sanitizedSting = spacedTags.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')

console.log(sanitizedSting);
```

and the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sN3N/).

I know those can be done using DOM manipulation which will probably be even faster but I'm trying to **avoid this**.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid DOM manipulation? This question isn't intended to criticise your approach, but it seems odd not to take the route you believe may be faster.

Comment: Well, this is for an AngularJS mobile app that allows the user to tap a word and swipe left/right to select words/sentence to style and comment the selection. I couldn't really figure out a way to think about it the "Angular Way" as suggested everywhere. So I'm heavily relying on $filter and RegEx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look for trailing and preceding spaces, then use the inner capture group as the replacement value you can achieve something similar.

```
var inputString = 'This is <b>a test</b> and this <i> is also a test</i>',
    spacedTags = inputString.replace(/(\s*(<\/[a-z]>|<[a-z]*>)\s*)/g, ' $2 '); 

console.log(spacedTags);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jcb5v/1/)

This looks for anything that matches a beginning or ending tag optionally surrounded by whitespace. it then uses the inner match as the replacement with added spaces on either side.

Both implementations, though, always leave a trailing space after any closing tag. `"</i> "`

I haven't looked in to the performance changes from this, but it attempts to address the issue of one regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem that you may add a space where there already is one? In that case, discard all spaces before and after your tag:

```
sanitizedSting = inputString.replace(/\s*(<\/?[a-z]*>)\s*/g, ' $1 ');
```

This also adds a space at the end if you end with a tag (frankly, there are other problems with this exact code).

Comment: This is a good answer. I have tested it in my code and it works perfectly. I can't see what could be wrong though, do you know what improvement or what kind of problems this could lead to?

Comment: It won't see `<A>`, nor `<h1>`, nor `<a href="..">`. It may add spaces where it should not, as in `an <em>example</em>.` and `test<!-- commented out>data`. Maybe some more.